# Saving various object information in easily acessible location

Tags: python, oop

I am trying to build a budgeting application which will help me build and manage money better.

I have identified that I need to manage three types of expenses: 
- Daily(Like transport costs, work snacks)
- Weekly Purchases(Like magazines, books)
- Monthly expenses(Rent, utilities)

I have written a generic class in Python which can capture all of these, but I would like to give myself more granular detail on how much each expense class costs me on a monthly basis and maybe out put this onto a calendar .

I would like to know how I can implement the above mentioned expense types as classes and have them all write to a common class where they can sorted and formatted into easily identified groups as "Daily", "Weekly", and "Monthly" but fall under a common interface where I can total expenses in the above mentions structure for quick viewing and planning etc.

Any suggestions? I am very much new to Python Coding- so far this idea has stumped me

Code:

```
class Expenses:

def __init__(self):
    self.list = []


"""Create dict containing expense"""
def add_expense(self, name, cost, describe):
    val = {"Name": name,
           "Cost": cost,
           "Description": describe
           }
    return self.list.append(val)


"""Show all of the expenses contained in the list self.list"""
def list_expenses(self):
    for i in self.list:
        for k, v in i.items():
            print('%s: %s' % (k, v))


"""add up the total of all expenses in self.list"""
def total_expenses(self):
    total = 0
    for i in self.list:
        for k, v in i.items():
            if k == "Cost":
                total += v
    return total


"""remove the given expense
   I should create a key that can be used as an indexer"""
def delete_expense(self, num):
    return self.list.pop(num)
```

This works as I want it - but like I was trying to allude too, I would like to add more detail to this class, I am using this to basically learn OOP. I do not mind using normal imperative code

Comment: Please add relevant portion of the code to improve the question.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, here you go

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I seriously believe you are over thinking it, but anyway I think the simplest solution for your problem is adding another property to your root class.
This property will determine the `time_span` of the expense (either daily, weekly or monthly),
and then you will be able to implement functions such as `daily_expenses(date)`, `weekly_expenses(time_range)` or `monthly_expenses(datetime_month)`
(your options for time ranges, or dates are practically endless..)

Comment: I most likely am thinking - like I said I am very much a rookie

I was wanting break everything up into smaller classes and have expense as its own class and use Getters and Setters to manipulate the list, but I suspect if I have more than one person using the app at any given time it would affect the over all list

Comment: 1. Python isn't intended to be used that way.. I assume you're trying to design your app that way because you're more familiar with a language such as C/C++/C#/Java which their best practices works as you are trying to do in python, python is about simplicity and readability
2. If more than one user will use the app the same time you should consider use some kind of database

Comment: I will be considering a database shortly, not to worry! I am just going to make some upgrades to my laptop over this weekend then ill move on to other topics.

See above, I posted some code

Comment: If this answer helped you I suggest you accept it as an answer